# Ext js: how to move element in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs, dom-manipulation

Is there a nice way in Ext to move elements in DOM? I want to move element 'iShouldBeInsideTheBox' inside the 'box' element and then back to it's original location in between two p elements:

```
<p>
    surrounding text
</p>
<p id="iShouldBeInsideTheBox">
    This should be inside the box
</p>
<p>
    surrounding text
</p>
<p id="box">
    Some content in the box
</p>
```

It took me four lines to do that in jQuery (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F2PXw/19/), but I can't think of easy ways to do that in Ext (or pure JS if it's reliable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what version do you want ??

ext 4.0.7 :
http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/cdLPA/

but, should work in old version...
never try : )

one more thing:
Please look carefully, the different between `Ext.get` and `Ext.query`
there is no `#` char in `Ext.get`

Comment: Ah, i see. Ext uses the same method names as regular JS. That will do, thanks!